# Firebase Admin not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to send a messaging but i have this error admin not defined.

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  my conig
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

setInterval(function(){

        // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
        var registrationToken = 'mytoken';

        var message = {
        data: {
            tittle: 'Tarea no Iniciada',
            body: 'Todavia no has iniciado tu tarea'
        },
        token: registrationToken
        };

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });

},3000);
```

This is my script, i use javascript not node.js

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: In an empty js. only have that <?= $this->Html->script('../js/notificaciones.js') ?> but first this have the script of firebase-app

Comment: Ok, thanks for the anwser. But do you execute this code from your client (i.e. your app, your front-end) or from a server?

Comment: ```var admin = require('firebase-admin');``` Have you initialized admin anywhere in your code? How are you running your code? Needs more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since, in your code, you are doing

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  my conig
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

it seems that you are initializing the [JavaScript SDK in a client application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and trying to call the Admin SDK from this client.

---

As you will read in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk), "the Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase **from privileged environments**".

With “privileged environment” the documentation means a server that you fully control or a Cloud Function in your Firebase Project that runs back-end code (and that you also control, since it is in your own Project).

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) for Firebase Cloud Messaging also clearly indicates that:

> The server side of Firebase Cloud Messaging consists of two
>   components:
>
> - The FCM backend provided by Google.
>     Your app server or other trusted server environment where your server logic runs, such as Cloud Functions for Firebase or other cloud
>     environments managed by Google.
> - **Your app server or trusted server environment** sends message requests
>     to the FCM backend, which then routes messages to client apps running
>     on users' devices.

Have also a look at the page on [FCM Architectural Overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture).

---

So you cannot use the Admin SDK from a client application to send a message. You need to either [set-up your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) or [use Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Comment: @daniellandete Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?